# Prevent Perl program from print newline after writing to sh terminal using system

Tags: linux, bash, shell, perl

I'm trying to extract data from a file to a Perl program and execute it in Linux sh terminal using "foreach" loop but every time Perl return value to sh terminal it will print a new line before print the next string which cause my script to fail. How do I prevent that?

```
open(FILE, "input") or die("Unable to open file");

# read file into an array
@data = <FILE>;

# close file 
close(FILE);

foreach my $x(@data) {
    system "/granite_api.pl -type update_backdoor -project tgplp -test_id $x -turninid 4206";
}
```

Expected output:

```
/granite_api.pl -type update_backdoor -project tgplp -test_id example -turninid 4206
```

Actual output:

```
/granite_api.pl -type update_backdoor -project tgplp -test_id example 
 -turninid 4206
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With

```
@data = <FILE>;
```

`@data` contains all lines from the input file. Each line ends with a LF. You need to remove it from each `$x`, using `chomp` for instance (that removes the trailing character(s) as set in `$/`)

```
foreach my $x ( @data ) {
    chomp $x;
    system "/granite_api.pl -type update_backdoor -project tgplp -test_id $x -turninid 4206";
}
```

See [`chomp` in `perldoc`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chomp.html)

Comment: `chomp` also works on lists: `chomp(@data);` will chomp all elements in `@data`.